# How to reassign value to a jira issue subfield using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq, jira

I'm having difficulties changing the value of a subfield in my json file. The json file is an extraction of a jira issue's fields (some of them anyways).

Here's the structure of a subset of my json:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "summary": "",
    "issuetype": {
      "self": "",
      "id": "",
      "description": "",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "name": "",
      "subtask": true,
      "avatarId": 17116
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to reassign just fields like `summary` using this command:

```
jq --arg field "$field" --arg value "$value" '.fields[$field] = $value' issue_fields.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json issue_fields.json
```

But I am having trouble changing subfields like `name` within the `issuetype` field.

```
jq --arg field "$field" --arg value "$value" --arg subfield "$subfield" '.fields[$field][$subfield] = $value' issue_fields.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json issue_fields.json
```

I keep getting errors like this: `Cannot index array with string "name"`

Comment: You are not showing the values of your variables. Is the JSON correct? "cannot index array" makes me think there is an array in your input document (but you are not showing it)

Comment: Field names in objects are strings, so use e.g. `--arg name "summary"`, just as you did before. But item indices in arrays are numbers, so you'd need to use e.g. `--argjson index 3`. The error message complains that you were using strings to index into an array.

Comment: Because this works just fine with the JSON of your question: `"issuetype" as $field
| "name" as $subfield
| "value" as $value
| .fields[$field][$subfield] = $value`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, everything looks copacetic, but as knittl mentioned, you may have your values set incorrectly. When I was first learning json and jq, I struggled with syntax because it can be temperamental until you grok the patterns (I still haven't fully - most haven't haha). Fortunately, `man jq` has lots of good info, and there are some great tutorials out on the internet.

Going through what you provided, I was able to get the expected results - here I want to change `summary` field to "hello world", so I set values like:

```bash
field="summary"
value="hello world"

# check vars with:
echo "field: '$field', value: '$value'"
```

And I got the expected results when I ran:

```bash
jq --arg field "$field" --arg value "$value" '.fields[$field] = $value' issue_fields.json
```

Same for when I wanted to modify one of the subfields under the `issuetype` fields

```bash
field="issuetype"
subfield="name"
value="issue type hello world"

# check vars
echo "field: '$field', subfield: '$subfield', value: '$value'"
```

Running the command listed for modifying subfield, I got expected results..

```bash
$ jq --arg field "$field" --arg value "$value" --arg subfield "$subfield" '.fields[$field][$subfield] = $value' issue_fields.json
```

Output:

```json
{
  "fields": {
    "summary": "",
    "issuetype": {
      "self": "",
      "id": "",
      "description": "",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "name": "issue type hello world",
      "subtask": true,
      "avatarId": 17116
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to reproduce your error if I set the variables incorrectly. Wondering if maybe you forgot to set the `field` variable to `issuetype`, (perhaps it was still set to `summary` from the first commands you were messing with).. (use `set -x` before the command to see more debugging, type `set +x` after to disable the extra debugging) :

```bash
# change the field to a field we know doesn't have subfields
$ field="summary"

# show the var values
$ echo "field: '$field', subfield: '$subfield', value: '$value'"
=>field: 'summary', subfield: 'name', value: 'issue type hello world'

$ set -x
=> + set -x
# the field 'summary' has no subfield (named 'name') so it will fail
$ jq --arg field "$field" --arg value "$value" --arg subfield "$subfield" '.fields[$field][$subfield] = $value' issue_fields.json
=> + jq --arg field summary --arg value 'issue type hello world' --arg subfield name '.fields[$field][$subfield] = $value' issue_fields.json
=> jq: error (at issue_fields.json:14): Cannot index string with string "name"

# turn off the debugging
$ set +x
```

Just to make sure I wasn't misleading you, I crafted up an example script that uses a case statement to determine if I want to change the `summary` field, or subfields under `issuetype`, and runs the appropriate command.

**myscript.sh contents:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# set a filename to use
fname="issue_fields.json"

# populate a file with example contents
cat > "${fname}" << EOF
{
  "fields": {
    "summary": "",
    "issuetype": {
      "self": "",
      "id": "",
      "description": "",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "name": "",
      "subtask": true,
      "avatarId": 17116
    }
  }
}
EOF

# arg1: field.subfield
# arg2: value

# field is the first value (before the dot)
field=${1%%.*}
# subfield is the next value (after the dot)
subfield=${1##*.}
value=${2}


# ensure 2 args
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
  echo "$0 takes exactly 2 args. $0 <field|field.subfield> <value>"
  exit 1
fi

# check if the field is summary
# check if the field is summary
case "${field}" in
  summary)
    jq --arg field "$field" \
       --arg value "$value" \
         '.fields[$field] = $value' "${fname}"
    ;;
  *)
    jq --arg field "$field" \
       --arg value "$value" \
       --arg subfield "$subfield" \
         '.fields[$field][$subfield] = $value' "${fname}"
    ;;
esac
```

Example usage:

```bash
$ ./myscript.sh issuetype.name "issue type name value"
{
  "fields": {
    "summary": "",
    "issuetype": {
      "self": "",
      "id": "",
      "description": "",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "name": "issue type name value",
      "subtask": true,
      "avatarId": 17116
    }
  }
}

# set summary
$ ./aa.sh summary hello
{
  "fields": {
    "summary": "hello",
    "issuetype": {
      "self": "",
      "id": "",
      "description": "",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "name": "",
      "subtask": true,
      "avatarId": 17116
    }
  }
}
```

Use the above and play around with things to get it where you want it.

You can also run it with `bash -x myscript.sh` to see debug output for more intuition into how it is working.